# Python: re.find longest sequence

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that is randomly generated:

```
polymer_str = "diol diNCO diamine diNCO diamine diNCO diamine diNCO diol diNCO diamine"
```

I'd like to find the longest sequence of "diNCO diol" and the longest of "diNCO diamine".  So in the case above the longest "diNCO diol" sequence is 1 and the longest "diNCO diamine" is 3.

How would I go about doing this using python's re module?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
I mean the longest number of repeats of a given string.  So the longest string with "diNCO diamine" is 3: 
diol **diNCO diamine diNCO diamine diNCO diamine** diNCO diol diNCO diamine

Comment: What do you mean by longest sequence? It appears to me you are doing exact-matching!

Comment: Thats sound like Bioinformatics :
Maybe the word "tandem repeat" is what you are looking for :
http://books.google.de/books?id=bIe-FPGhed0C&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=python+tandem+repeats&source=bl&ots=6aR-PERsZg&sig=XbnRQZpNldf1t31-iIcyl-wOgiA&hl=de&ei=bNZkSqzfL4XWmgOW4sCCBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1

Comment: n00ki3, i'm looking for the largest block.  "diNCO diamine" is a repeating block and I want to know what the largest block is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expanding on [Ealdwulf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90354/ealdwulf)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155376/python-re-find-longest-sequence/1155508#1155508):

Documentation on `re.findall` can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall).

```
def getLongestSequenceSize(search_str, polymer_str):
    matches = re.findall(r'(?:\b%s\b\s?)+' % search_str, polymer_str)
    longest_match = max(matches)
    return longest_match.count(search_str)
```

This could be written as one line, but it becomes less readable in that form.

**Alternative:**

If `polymer_str` is huge, it will be more memory efficient to use `re.finditer`.  Here's how you might go about it:

```
def getLongestSequenceSize(search_str, polymer_str):
    longest_match = ''
    for match in re.finditer(r'(?:\b%s\b\s?)+' % search_str, polymer_str):
        if len(match.group(0)) > len(longest_match):
            longest_match = match.group(0)
    return longest_match.count(search_str)
```

The biggest difference between `findall` and `finditer` is that the first returns a list object, while the second iterates over Match objects.  Also, the `finditer` approach will be somewhat slower.

Comment: This actually returns the number of characters in the final match, not the number of matches (as seems to be suggested in the question) and not a string containing the longest match.

Comment: Good point, I've fixed the code to return the number of matches.  If they want the actual string, they just need to return 'longest_match'.

Answer (score 3):

I think the op wants the longest contiguous sequence. You can get all contiguous sequences like:

```
seqs = re.findall("(?:diNCO diamine)+", polymer_str)
```

and then find the longest.

Comment: I've expanded on this in my answer.

Comment: tgray has mostly done it. I would only add that the '?:' rune is necessary as otherwise findall returns each match inside the parentheses as a separate entry in the list, which in this case defeats the object.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
pat = re.compile("[^|]+")
p = "diol diNCO diamine diNCO diamine diNCO diamine diNCO diol diNCO diamine".replace("diNCO diamine","|").replace(" ","")
print max(map(len,pat.split(p)))
```

Answer (score 0):

One was is to use `findall`:

```
polymer_str = "diol diNCO diamine diNCO diamine diNCO diamine diNCO diol diNCO diamine"
len(re.findall("diNCO diamine", polymer_str)) # returns 4.
```

Comment: That finds the total number, not the longest sequence

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using re:

```
m = re.search(r"(\bdiNCO diamine\b\s?)+", polymer_str)
len(m.group(0)) / len("bdiNCO diamine")
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the spaces correctly. You also have an extra "b" in the second line. +1 for being closer than I was!

Comment: How would you solve the spaces problem?

You are right about the 'b'. That's the problem of copy&paste :)

Comment: This does not work.  It finds the first match, not the longest match.  polymer_str = "diol diNCO diamine tacos diNCO diamine diNCO diamine diNCO diamine diNCO diol diNCO diamine" The correct result is 3; this returns 1.

Comment: Actually group(0) gets overwritten every time a new match is found.  There is currently no way to get multiple groups from a '+' or '*' in a regex using the 're' module.